# Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException / HTTP1.1 Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, webforms, updatepanel

I've perused the forums for a couple weeks now trying out different solutions, but nothing seems to be helping. Here's my problem:

I have created an ASP.NET Web Application for displaying dashboard-style metrics in a Service Desk setting. The client has large screens in the service desk room that display specific pages of my web app.

Some pages use UpdatePanel, others use $.ajax to make calls to code behind every 15 seconds (I have various [WebMethod]'s set up for the ajax calls).

These dashboards work fantastic for about a day, maybe 2, then they stop refreshing, and the above error message can be found in the console. Bug checking for the ajax methods show they hit the 'error:' portion of the ajax call.

Below are solutions I have tried to no avail:

Added `EnableSessionState="False"` to the `<%@ Page %>` header.

Added `validateRequest="false"` to the `<%@ Page %>` header.

Added `enableEventValidation="false"` to the `<%@ Page %>` header.

Added try-catch statements to my web methods to catch the error.

Added Global.asax and overrode the Application_Error. Made it write to an application event log. Example below.

```
Exception exc = Server.GetLastError().GetBaseException();
        if (!EventLog.SourceExists("Dashboards"))
        {
            EventLog.CreateEventSource("Dashboards", "Dashboard");
        }

        EventLog log = new EventLog();
        log.Source = "Dashboards";
        log.WriteEntry(exc.ToString());

        Server.ClearError();
```

This Global.asax exception is never called (as far as I can tell) and I never have any exceptions logged.

I can't think of any other troubleshooting to do with this.

If I had to guess, I would say it's the every 15 second ajax/updatepanel calls that is causing the issue. The app is running on IIS v8 on Server 2012. Perhaps IIS thinks it's getting DDOS'd or something similar? Another possibility is that I have various threads running in the code behind (aspx.cs) updating information that the ajax call then pulls from. Maybe the thread is getting killed somehow?

I am currently out of ideas. Any help with troubleshooting would be appreciated. I'm more than happy to upload more code as example as well.

Thank you to anyone who can assist with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue after extensive research.

These web pages are naturally long-running (they are dashboards that are displayed and updated continuously in a service desk environment) and they have various long-running threads that perform operations in the background.

IIS has functionality to recycle application pools, and by default the interval is set to 29 hours, which coincidentally was the interval of the internal server errors.

Since this is the only application running on this server, and there are a select few computers that will be accessing this website, I disabled the application pool recycle. This immediately fixed the problem.

I will be checking the server on a regular basis to make sure this change does not cause any other adverse issues, but so far so good.

Hopefully this helps anyone else having this issue with long running web applications.